# How to stop React re-rendering without state value update?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

I have a react state

```
const [newState, setNewState] = useState({a:1, b:2})
```

I have a useEffect which performs certain operation on state update

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(newState)
    ....
    ....
},[newState])
```

Now if the state is updated in following manner

```
setNewState(prevState => ({...prevState, b:2})
```

it does not  cause a re-render as expected because values did not update. However, it is re rendering if state is updated in following manner

```
updatedState = {a:1, b:2}
setNewState(prevState => ({...prevState, ...updatedState})
```

even though state values remain same. This update is causing re render. I am not sure why this is happening. Also I want to know how to stop the re rendering if I want to update the state in second way.